# morphia and gson mixing for mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, gson, morphia

my question is much more about taking an advice then code issues since i haven't started, i would like to know if it's beneficial to mix Google Gson with Morphia in order to deal with mongodb json objects;

My app will be interacting with an already existing database (that's where the need to gson serialization)

**Gson** would be mainly used to O/J map the JSON to/from Java POJOs/entities.
**Morphia**  to drive connectivity from my Java app to Mongo
is there a better approch than this? If so, links and documentations are most welcome

Answer (score 1):

There's not much downside to that approach.  For starters, it sounds like gson is a hard requirement.  But annotation-wise, morphia can be pretty lightweight.  There's just not a lot of decoration absolutely need for things to work.  If you were using jackson, I believe Jongo uses those annotations directly so you could save yourself a little double mapping but i don't think it'll be terrible either way.

Comment: Thanks for your help